# Size of Firebase Database?

Tags: android, firebase-realtime-database

I am building an app where I am going to have chat. When I send message from backend that message is stored in Database on Firebase console. My question is: Is there any constraint about size of data who are in Firebase console Database and, when I send from backend that data to database and from there to my Android device, will that data in database be deleted when data comes to the device or not?

Comment: Data is not automatically deleted from the Firebase Database. That would be fairly unexpected behavior for an online database.

Comment: And what about maximum size of data in database?

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen How many child references can we have under the root of firebase real time database and as the number increases how does it effect the access latency or update latency.